# How to get user's timezone and convert time saved in database according to the user's timezone? Please see details

Tags: android, datetime, date-format, simpledateformat, android-date

I'm developing an app in which I'm saving the time when the post was posted.

I'm getting that time by using this code:

```
DateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
final String time = currentTime.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Now, what I want is I want to get user's timezone and convert the time saved in database using his/her timezone to his/her local time.

I tried doing this using code:

```
public String convertTime(Date d) {
    //You are getting server date as argument, parse your server response and then pass date to this method

    SimpleDateFormat sdfAmerica = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");

    String actualTime = sdfAmerica.format(d);

    //Changed timezone
    TimeZone tzInAmerica = TimeZone.getDefault();
    sdfAmerica.setTimeZone(tzInAmerica);

    convertedTime = sdfAmerica.format(d);

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "actual : " + actualTime + "  converted " + convertedTime, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return convertedTime;
}
```

but this is not changing the time.

This is how I'm trying to convert time saved in database using above method (`postedAtTime` is the time which is getting retrieved from database):

```
String timeStr = postedAtTime;
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
Date date = null;
try {
    date = df.parse(timeStr);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
convertTime(date);
```

Please let me know what's wrong in my code or if this is wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time string you're storing is not sufficient to be able to change timezones after the fact (h:mm a is only hours, minutes and am/pm marker). In order to do something like this you need to either store the timezone the original timestamp was in or better yet store the time in a deterministic manner like always UTC.

Example code:

```
    final Date now = new Date();
    final String format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
    // Convert to UTC for persistence
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    // Persist string to DB - UTC timezone
    final String persisted = sdf.format(now);
    System.out.println(String.format(Locale.US, "Date is: %s", persisted));

    // Parse string from DB - UTC timezone
    final Date parsed = sdf.parse(persisted);

    // Now convert to whatever timezone for display purposes
    final SimpleDateFormat displayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a Z", Locale.US);
    displayFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));

    final String display = displayFormat.format(parsed);
    System.out.println(String.format(Locale.US, "Date is: %s", display));
```

Output

```
Date is: 2016-06-24 17:49:43
Date is: 13:49 PM -0400
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, bro. Can you please suggest a piece of code?

Comment: Assuming you can't change your DB schema and the date needs to be persisted as a string (example added to answer)

Comment: I can change my database... pls let me know how can I make this work?